# Confusing datasheet for JFET 113: Which value for IDSS applies?

Tags: current, datasheet, jfet

I am trying to build a small amplifier with a JFET J113 to get a high input impedance. I have a problem with the [datasheet:](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2285689.pdf)

On page 3 it gives a value of IDSS=2mA for J113. However, on the following pages it shows universal curves for all three JFETs J111, J112 and J113.

On figure 5 you find that all these transistors have at least 18mA at VGS=0V.

Which value should I use? If it is the one from page 3, will I have to calculate my own curve using the general JFET-models or can I still somehow use the graphs?

Comment: Page 3 is a *minimum* value. Figure 5 gives *typical* characteristics. Yes the spread really can be that large. Design so taht the spread doesn't matter.

Comment: That makes sense! Meanwhile I measured a few samples and they were perfectly in line with the graphs. Thanks!